# Find font file from font name on Linux

Tags: find, fonts, search, file-search

I have a font with the name *Media Gothic*. How can I find the file name of that font in Linux? I need to copy that file to another system. I've tried:

```
find /usr/share/fonts/ -name '*media*'
```

But this gives no results. `gothic` gives some other fonts. TTF is a binary format so I can't use `grep`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
fc-list | grep -i "media"
```

Also give a try to `fc-scan`, `fc-match`

Comment: Didn't know about `fc-*` commands. Thanks.

Comment: How does this help locate the actual font file? The font **file** name might be (at best) a scrambled version of the actual **font** name.

Comment: yes it does list the font name and the (sometimes scrambled) filename

Answer (score 4):

`fc-list FontName file`

where `FontName` is the *exact* font name found with

`fc-list | grep -i approximate-or-partial-font-name`

Comment: This is exact answer as accepted one.

Comment: On newer systems - yes, but on older ones `fc-list` withouth the `file` command does not show filenames for the fonts listed. And the `file` command could only be specified after a FontName.

Comment: You should mention that in answer, that on older system accepted answer don't show files names and you need to call fc-list again to get the filename.

Comment: Portable 1-liner (w/ extra, automating steps). `fc-list $(fc-list|grep -i <apprx-part-font-name>|head -n 1|awk '{print $NF}') file|sed 's/: $//'`. **e.g.**, Unifont; steps - in: `$` `fc-list|grep -i unifont`, out: 1st of 3 lines: `/usr/share/fonts/unifont-fonts/unifont-14.0.01.ttf: Unifont:style=Regular'`.Just name - in: `$` `fc-list|grep -i unifont|head -n1|awk '{print $NF}'`, out: `Unifont:style=Regular`.Answer above - in: `$` `fc-list $(fc-list|grep -i unifont|head -n 1|awk '{print $NF}') file`, out: `/usr/share/fonts/unifont-fonts/unifont-14.0.01.ttf:` Lose colon w/ pipe to `sed 's/: $//'`